# Can I use the Motion class in a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, accelerometer

Working on a project for a client must use Windows Phone 8.1 (on Lumia 640 phones). The project includes measuring the acceleration of an object in motion. Whilst I can access the accelerometer sensor, and read the current G-forces, they include gravity in the results and so need to exclude gravity from the acceleration results.

I think we need to access a linear acceleration measurement that seems to be available from the [Motion Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.sensors.motion(v=vs.105).aspx)  as part of the [MotionReading structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.sensors.motionreading(v=vs.105).aspx)

Looks great but I can't get Visual Studio (c#) to allow me to include the Microsoft.Devices.Sensors API in my app and Windows.Devices.Sensors (Which I can access and use) does not have the same functionality.

Anyone with experience with the Motion class and Windows Phone 8.1 can you point me in the right direction, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like *Motion* class is available only for *Windows Phone Silverlight* only - if you create such project, the namespace should be there. However I cannot find any documentation referring to this, the [Motion description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.sensors.motion(v=vs.105).aspx) says only about *Windows Phone* doesn't specifying if it's *Silverlight* or *Runtime*, also [Migration reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642486(v=vs.105).aspx) doesn't help much with this.

Comment: Thanks Romasz, confirmed Motion is available in Phones Silverlight. As you mentioned Motion documentation is very unclear if this is Runtime or Silverlight! I think I'll have to assume its Silverlight only sadly.